# count and percent in same query

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query to obtain a number of counts based on WHERE parameters.

I'd like to be able to include the percent of each group based off of the count(i131ID) but I can't seem to get the query to return results.

Original Query:

```
SELECT MAX(counthypo) counthypo, MAX(counteuthyroid) counteuthyroid, MAX(counthyper) counthyper, MAX(none) none, MAX(unknown) unknown

FROM (
      SELECT count(*) as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, 0 as none, 0 as unknown
      FROM tbl_I131_data
      WHERE `recheck_t4` < `recheck_t4_range_low` 

      UNION 

      SELECT 0 as counthypo, count(*) as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, 0 as none, 0 as unknown
      FROM tbl_I131_data
      WHERE (`recheck_t4` BETWEEN `recheck_t4_range_low` AND `recheck_t4_range_high`)

      UNION

      SELECT 0 as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, count(*) as counthyper, 0 as none, 0 as unknown
      FROM tbl_I131_data
      WHERE `recheck_t4` > `recheck_t4_range_high` 

      UNION

      SELECT 0 as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, count(*) as none, 0 as unknown
      FROM tbl_I131_data
      WHERE `nordvmfollowup` = '1' AND `isotope` = '1'

      UNION

      SELECT 0 as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, 0 as none, count(*) as unknown
      FROM tbl_I131_data      
      WHERE `recheck_t4` is null AND `isotope` = '1' and `nordvmfollowup` is null

     ) i
```

I've tried doing a CROSS JOIN, using

```
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) as total
FROM tbl_I131_data i131
) i2
```

And then at the original SELECT, I've tried something like

```
SELECT MAX(counthypo) counthypo, (counthypo/total)*100 AS percHypo, MAX(counteuthyroid) counteuthyroid, MAX(counthyper) counthyper, MAX(none) none, MAX(unknown) unknown
```

I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: So, each of the other things you tried produced no results, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to  `group by total`
so the whole query would be

```
SELECT MAX(counthypo) AS counthypo, (MAX(counthypo)/total)*100 AS percHypo, MAX(counteuthyroid) counteuthyroid, MAX(counthyper) counthyper, MAX(none) none, MAX(unknown) unknown

FROM (
       SELECT count(*) as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, 0 as none, 0 as unknown
       FROM tbl_I131_data

       WHERE `recheck_t4` < `recheck_t4_range_low`

       UNION

       SELECT 0 as counthypo, count(*) as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, 0 as none, 0 as unknown
       FROM tbl_I131_data
       WHERE (`recheck_t4` BETWEEN `recheck_t4_range_low` AND `recheck_t4_range_high`)

       UNION

       SELECT 0 as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, count(*) as counthyper, 0 as none, 0 as unknown
       FROM tbl_I131_data
       WHERE `recheck_t4` > `recheck_t4_range_high`

       UNION

       SELECT 0 as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, count(*) as none, 0 as unknown
       FROM tbl_I131_data
       WHERE `nordvmfollowup` = '1' AND `isotope` = '1'

       UNION

       SELECT 0 as counthypo, 0 as counteuthyroid, 0 as counthyper, 0 as none, count(*) as unknown
       FROM tbl_I131_data
       WHERE `recheck_t4` is null AND `isotope` = '1' and `nordvmfollowup` is null

     ) i
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) as total
 FROM tbl_I131_data as i131
) i2
group by i2.total
```

Comment: or  this 
(MAX(counthypo)/MAX(total))*100 AS percHypo
with removing the group by i2.total

Comment: thanks, the above worked perfectly! thanks for the help on that!!! have a great day!